# C++ equivalent of python: tf.Graph.get_tensor_by_name() in Tensorflow?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

What is the C++ equivalent of python: tf.Graph.get_tensor_by_name(name) in Tensorflow? Thanks!

Here is the code I am trying to run, but I get an empty `output`:

```
Status status = NewSession(SessionOptions(), &session); // create new session
ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), model, &graph_def); // read Graph
session->Create(graph_def); // add Graph to Tensorflow session 
std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> output; // create Tensor to store output
std::vector<string> vNames; // vector of names for required graph nodes
vNames.push_back("some_name"); // I checked names and they are presented in loaded Graph

session->Run({}, vNames, {}, &output); // ??? As a result I have empty output
```

Comment: What type of C++ object do you have?

Comment: I use the following sequence:

<code> Status status = NewSession(SessionOptions(), &session); // create new session
    ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), model, &graph_def); // read Graph
session->Create(graph_def); // add Graph to Tensorflow session

std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> output; // create Tensor to store output
std::vector<string> vNames; // vector of names for required graph nodes

vNames.push_back("some_name"); // I checked names and they are presented in loaded Graph

session->Run({}, vNames, {}, &output); // ??? As a result I have empty output<code>

Answer (score 3):

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378657/c-equivalent-of-python-tf-graph-get-tensor-by-name-in-tensorflow#comment66102218_39378657), it sounds like you are using the C++ `tensorflow::Session` API, which represents graphs as `GraphDef` protocol buffers. There is **no equivalent** to [`tf.Graph.get_tensor_by_name()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph.get_tensor_by_name) in this API.

Instead of passing typed [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor) objects to [`Session::Run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/cc/ClassSession.html#virtual_Status_tensorflow_Session_Run), you pass the `string` names of tensors, which have the form `<NODE NAME>:<N>`, where `<NODE NAME>` matches one of the `NodeDef.name` values in the `GraphDef`, and `<N>` is an integer corresponding to the index of the the output from that node that you want to fetch.

The code in your question looks roughly correct, but there are two things I'd advise:

1. The `session->Run()` call returns a `tensorflow::Status` value. If `output` is empty after the the call returns, it is almost certain that the call returned an error status with a message that explains the problem.
2. You're passing `"some_name"` as the name of a tensor to fetch, but it is the name of a node, not a tensor. It is possible that this API requires you to specify the output index explicitly: try replacing it with `"some_name:0"`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It and [these](https://habrahabr.ru/post/308002/) examples helped me to understand.

Comment: What are the alternatives to using the C++ `tensorflow::Session` API for this?

Answer (score 3):

there is a way to get neural node from graph_def directly. 
if u only want the shape\type of node: "some_name":

```
void readPB(GraphDef & graph_def)
{

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < graph_def.node_size(); i++)
    {
        if (graph_def.node(i).name() == "inputx")
        {
            graph_def.node(i).PrintDebugString();
        }
    }
}
```

results:

```
name: "inputx"
op: "Placeholder"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "shape"
  value {
    shape {
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: 5120
      }
    }
  }
}
```

try member functins of the node and get the informations.

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody is interested, here is how you extract the shape of an arbitrary sensor from graph_def using the tensorflow C++ API

```
vector<int64_t> get_shape_of_tensor(tensorflow::GraphDef graph_def, std::string name_tensor)
{
    vector<int64_t> tensor_shape;
    for (int i=0; i < graph_def.node_size(); ++i) {
        if (graph_def.node(i).name() == name_tensor) {
            auto node = graph_def.node(i);
            auto attr_map = node.attr();
            for (auto it=attr_map.begin(); it != attr_map.end(); it++) {
                auto key = it->first;
                auto value = it->second;
                if (value.has_shape()) {
                    auto shape = value.shape();
                    for (int i=0; i<shape.dim_size(); ++i) {
                        auto dim = shape.dim(i);
                        auto dim_size = dim.size();
                        tensor_shape.push_back(dim_size);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return tensor_shape
}
```