# How do I use Tensorflow c++ to implement this code (FaceNet)?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, face-recognition

## [FaceNet](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet).by David sandberg

FaceNet uses python to implement the code:

```
#load graph
with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

# We load the graph_def in the default graph
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session(graph=graph, config=config) as sess:
    with sess.as_default():

    image_batch = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
    phase_train_placeholder = graph.get_tensor_by_name("phase_train:0")
    embeddings = graph.get_tensor_by_name("embeddings:0")
    feed_dict = {image_batch: np.expand_dims(face, 0), phase_train_placeholder: False}
    rep = sess.run(embeddings, feed_dict=feed_dict)
    #do something by 'rep'
    #....
```

Now use C++ to implement this code:

```
Session* session;

// Initialize a tensorflow session
Status status = NewSession(SessionOptions(), &session);
if (!status.ok()) {
    std::cout << status.ToString() << "\n";
    return 1;
}

//Load graph ...

GraphDef graph_def;
status = ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), "250000.pb", &graph_def);
if (!status.ok()) {
    std::cout << status.ToString() << "\n";
    return 1;
}
/*
How do I use "get_tensor_by_name" ??

std::vector<Tensor> out_tensors;
TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(session->Run({}, {output_name + ":0", output_name + ":1"},
                                      {}, &out_tensors));
*/
```

How to use get_tensor_by_name in Tensorflow C++?

How to call the run method, and the above python code to achieve the same purpose?

#### The tensor image_batch: np.expand_dims (image_data, 0) needs to be passed into a matrix value, how do I write this np.expand_dims (image_data, 0)?

This is a good tip:[Import OpenCV Mat into C++ Tensorflow without copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379747/import-opencv-mat-into-c-tensorflow-without-copying)

There is no problem now, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ library has no equivalent. You just pass the names of the tensors instead of the tensor objects.

```
string image_batch = "input:0";
string phase_train_placeholder = "phase_train:0";
string embeddings = "embeddings:0";
```

See this question: [C++ equivalent of python: tf.Graph.get_tensor_by_name() in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378657/c-equivalent-of-python-tf-graph-get-tensor-by-name-in-tensorflow/39394704#39394704)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I still have a problem, tensor image_batch: np.expand_dims (image_data, 0) need to be passed into a matrix value, how do I write this np.expand_dims (image_data, 0)

Comment: np is Numpy, you might be better off asking another question. That isn't part of TensorFlow.

Comment: Yes, I just want to know how to write np.expand_dims (image_data, 0) in c ++, maybe Tensorflow has the same method. Anyway, thank you. I will ask a new question for this