# How to get placeholder size in TensorFlow C++ API?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I want to use C++ to load TensorFlow model. And I want to know size of model's input, which is the placeholder in the model.

I google this problem, but I just find this link in stackoverflow :

> [C++ equivalent of python: tf.Graph.get_tensor_by_name() in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378657/c-equivalent-of-python-tf-graph-get-tensor-by-name-in-tensorflow)

Although I can get node, but tensorflow document don't tell me how to access the size of the node. So is there anyone know something about this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for your supporting. The downvote nearly let me down. And do you know how to get the size? And I search the tensorflow source code in github, and didn't find useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK，after many times attempts. I have find a workaround solution, It maybe tricky but works well.

At first, we can get the placeholder node using following code:

```
GraphDef mygd = graph_def.graph_def();
for (int i = 0; i < mygd.node_size(); i++)
{
    if (mygd.node(i).name() == input_name)
    {
        auto node = mygd.node(i);
    }
}
```

Then through the NodeDef.pd.h(tensorflow/core/framework/node_def.pb.h), we can get AttrValue through code like below:

```
auto attr = node.attr();
```

Then through the attr_value.cc(tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value.cc), we can get the shape attr value through code like below:

```
tensorflow::AttrValue shape = attr["shape"];
```

and the shape AttrValue is the structure used to store shape information. We can get the detail information through the function SummarizeAttrValue in tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value_util.h

```
string size_summary = SummarizeAttrValue(shape);
```

And then we can get the string format of shape like below:

```
[?,1024]
```