# Get the input and output node information of the model through the c ++ tensorflow interface

Tags: c++, tensorflow

The following code fails to compile under tensorflow 1.13.1:

```
GraphDef graph_def;
status = ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), modelPath, &graph_def);
if (!status.ok()) {
     std::cerr << "ReadBinaryProto Status：" << status.ToString() << endl;
     return -1;
}
cout << "success." << endl;
int a = graph_def.node_size();

int i;
for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
    graph_def.node(i).PrintDebugString();
}
return -1;
```

Compile error message

> Unresolved external symbol "public: class google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage & __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(char const *)" (??6LogMessage@internal@protobuf@google@@QEAAAEAV0123@PEBD@Z)
>   Unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::LogFinisher::operator=(class google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage &)" (??4LogFinisher@internal@protobuf@google@@QEAAXAEAVLogMessage@123@@Z)
>   Unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl google::protobuf::Message::PrintDebugString(void)const " (?PrintDebugString@Message@protobuf@google@@QEBAXXZ)
>   Unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::LogMessage(enum google::protobuf::LogLevel,char const *,int)" (??0LogMessage@internal@protobuf@google@@QEAA@W4LogLevel@23@PEBDH@Z)
>   Unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::~LogMessage(void)" (??1LogMessage@internal@protobuf@google@@QEAA@XZ)

all the above operations appeared under visual studio 2015.

Comment: ok，already put in, are there any other questions?

Comment: These are linkers errors. Please provide commands / CMakeLists.txt / indications used to build this code.

Comment: The tensorflow dll and lib files are compiled by bazel. Do you mean that something went wrong during compilation and needs to be recompiled again?

Comment: Is this code part of Tensorflow, or is it yours ?

Comment: my test code，I want to get the input and output node information of the model through tensorflow。<br />Similar to the code in this answer<br />https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378657/c-equivalent-of-python-tf-graph-get-tensor-by-name-in-tensorflow

Comment: You have to build/install correctly the Tensorflow libraries, as well as its needed dependencies (such as protobuf), then you have to configure Visual Studio 2015 correctly so that it can link to Tensorflow (I cannot help with that, sorry).

Comment: thanks,I am trying to recompile the tensorflow dll and lib files to see if there is still this error.

Comment: I am sure there are tutorials for that online. Your error as is does not particularly hint hat a problem with building Tensorflow.

Comment: hi,I solved the problem,I will organize the solution later.

Answer (score 1):

Add the code suggested in the compilation error message to the end of the file in the link.
File link to be modified:
https://github.com/guikarist/tensorflow-windows-build-script/blob/master/patches/tf_exported_symbols_msvc.lds
[image: **enter image description here**]

then recompile tensorflow.
refer to the following link for the entire compilation process.
https://blog.csdn.net/atpalain_csdn/article/details/97945536